# Asymptotics of integral representation of distribution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Background: I am studying the PDE $$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,i\partial_t \psi(x,t)=-\Delta\psi-\epsilon^4\Delta^2\psi\\ \psi(x,0)=f(x)$$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}, t\ge 0$, $\epsilon>0$ small, and $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. I am particularly interested in the behavior of $\psi$ in the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$. It is alreacy clear the the limit will be quite singular as the order of the PDE changes suddenly as soon as $\epsilon\neq 0$.  The Fourier transform in space of $\psi$, denoted $\widetilde{\psi}(k,t)$, satisfies
$$\widetilde{\psi}(k,t)=e^{-itk^2}e^{i\epsilon^4 t k^4}\widetilde{f}(k).$$
Let $\psi_0(x,t)$ denote the solution to the PDE when setting $\epsilon=0$. Then,
$$\widetilde{\psi}(k,t)=\widetilde{\psi_0}e^{i\epsilon^4 t k^4}.$$ Inverting the Fourier transform, we find that
$$\psi(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi_0(y,t)\,F_\epsilon(x-y,t)\,dy,$$
where
$$F_\epsilon(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}e^{i\epsilon^4 tk^4}\,dk$$
We treat $F$ as a tempered distribution since we uniquely care about its action on an element of $\mathcal{S}$, in this case $\psi_0$, which gives us the solution to the desired PDE. As distributions, $F_0(x,t)=\delta_x$. My question for this post is as follows: is it correct, to expand $e^{i\epsilon^4 tk^4}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty (i\epsilon^4 t)^m k^{4m}$, switch the order of integration and integrate to obtain
$$F_\epsilon(x,t)=\delta_x+\sum_{m=1}^\infty (i\epsilon^4 t)^m \,\delta^{\,(4m)}_x,$$
where $\delta^{(n)}_x$ is the $n$-th derivative of the dirac mass at $x$?
If not, what is the correct way to proceed to find an asymptotic expansion of $F_\epsilon$ as $\epsilon\to 0$? Or is there a better way to proceed to understand the behavior of the solutions to this PDE for small $\epsilon$?

Comment: Not that it matters much, but is the sign of the perturbation negative on purpose?

Comment: I'm asking this question because your problem seems a quantum mechanical problem with Hamiltonian $H= p^2  - p^4$. Of course the time dependent solution is given precisely by your integral.

Comment: Your approximation reminds me of the [Edgeworth series in probability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series)

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423874/asymptotics-of-integral-representation-of-distribution

Comment: Yes, the sign is negative on purpose. The problem is about the relativistic Hamiltonian $H=\sqrt{m^2+p^2}-m$ in the limit of small $p/m$. The approximation then takes the form $H \sim p^2-p^4$.